# GET запросы, проблема с сортировкой цены, не правильно отображает при запросе

Tags: php, get

**Всем привет.**
Сделал на сайте поиск по фильтрам, поиск работает по типу добавление параметров в урл, GET.
Автомобильный поиск, марки, модели, находит отлично, там слова.
Есть год, показывает тож хорошо.

А вот поиск по цене и пробегу, там цифры, работает не корректно.
Допустим, у меня есть цена на авто, 1 000 000, и до 5 000 000. В бд так и записано, вместо точек и запятых пробелы, в поиске я выбираю показывать от 5 000 000, параметр стоит в php, показывать данную цену и все что выше идет, >and_where('price', '>=', $price); а показывает он мне и ниже 5 000 000.
В урле что я вижу при таком поиске: /auto/?marka=&model=&god=&probeg=&price=5+000+000

Я пробовал в бд, убрать пробелы у цен, и так же в поиске в запросе GET, и все равно он показывал мне суммы меньше.

Поле price бд, у него параметр варчар, цена записывается с пробелами, так (5 000 000).

Что может быть не так?

Comment: "Что может быть не так" ---> "Поле price бд, у него параметр варчар, цена записывается с пробелами"

Comment: Так я же пишу, что я пробовал и так 5000000 без точек, без запятых и пробелов, ставил и  decimal(10,6)

Comment: Странно выходит, если я в ручную в бд в поле вбиваю суммы, то работает ок, если я через функцию сохраняю, там тож без пробелов, точек и запятых, то не работает как надо.

Я там просто курс валюты умножаю на сумму и получаю price, по которому и ищу Get м.

Все у price поставил decimal(10,0) и все работает.

А вчера не смог разобраться )

Comment: *1 000 000, и до 5 000 000. В бд так и записано* - для начала в бд сделайте без пробелов

Comment: С пробегом у меня чуть ругая ситуация, есть вариант без пробега, это  запрос GET 0, если выбираю, то он показывает все варианты, а не те где есть 0. 
У поля пробег в бд, тож поставил decimal(10,0)

Comment: Интересная логика - "цена это число, но поле под него будет строкой".